# What language is TeX implemented in?

Tags: tex-core, tex-history, web

I read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) that the first version of TeX was written in SAIL. However, does anyone know what language later versions (i.e the current one) are implemented in?

Comment: The sources are written in a variety of Pascal.

Comment: LaTeX has been ported to javascript: http://manuels.github.com/texlive.js/website/

Comment: ["The language used is called WEB and produces programs in DEC PDP-10 Pascal."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX#History)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

TeX was rewritten in Pascal. Actually, using a literate programming system called [WEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming#Tools), invented by Knuth himself. This system uses Pascal for the programming and it uses TeX for the documentation.

The source code of TeX was published as a book: [http://www.amazon.com/Computers-Typesetting-B-TeX-Program/dp/0201134373](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201134373).

Comment: Currently, TeXLive uses `web2c` to compile WEB source in C. Pascal is not longer used since many years...

Comment: @zunbeltz The commented source is also available in TeX Live with `texdoc tex`.

Comment: I do not agree with the idea that since `web2c` is used to compile the Pascal parts of the Web code to C, then Pascal is no longer being used or that the code is no longer written in Pascal.

Comment: @Kaz: TeX (& Co.) is written in WEB... The subset of Pascal produced by tangle is just used as an intermediate between WEB and C.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: If you need to hack a TeX you still have to use Pascal (unless you are hacking LuaTeX which have been ported to C), so it *is* Pascal for most practical, the `web2c` translation can be seen as a compilation detail. And there is [TeX-GPC](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/unix/tex-gpc) where the Pascal code is directly compiled.

Comment: @KhaledHosny In pdftex sources, we find 42882 lines in .WEB files, 17559 lines in .ch files (.ch files are like Pascal diff files, we can therefore divide their size by 2 or 3) and 194882 lines of .c or .h files...

Comment: @PaulGaborit: I don’t know where you are looking, but `pdftexdir` (which is the PDFTeX source) has only 14450 lines of C and headers, almost all of them are for handling fonts and images embedded in PDF files.

Comment: @KhaledHosny I look into http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/pdftex/pdftex-1.40.11.zip

Comment: @PaulGaborit: This tarball includes not only PDFTeX source code, but also the entire web2c system, kpathsea, a bunch of support libraries (zlib, xpdf, libpng, etc.) and even the source code for WEB and CWEB utilities. That is hardly the source code for TeX.

Answer (score 44):

TeX is written in [WEB](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/knuth/webman.pdf) (a literate programming language created by D. E. Knuth).

Originally, WEB source was translated into Pascal (a subset of Pascal) via `tangle` to produce executable and translated into TeX via `weave` to produce documentation of the code. Both programs have themselves been written in WEB.

Today, TeXLive uses `web2c` to translate directly WEB source into C... via the Pascal source produced by tangle (`web2c` is not a Pascal to C translator).

MikTeX must use a similar system to produce C/C++.